# Hard to find spatula

Tags: equipment

Just curious if you ever found where to buy those spatulas? (Re: Where did the thin, smooth plastic spatulas go? The dark blue one on the left)
[Where did the thin, smooth plastic spatulas go?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/18682/where-did-the-thin-smooth-plastic-spatulas-go)

My wife would like to get some too but I can't find that type either.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you looked on Amazon? Something like this seems to be exactly what you're looking for, but there are many others to choose from:
http://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B0000VLUDK

Comment: @ElmerCat thats not even remotely close.

Comment: Hello John, we are not a discussion forum, and our questions are not just the transcript of a conversation somebody has had long ago, they are meant to be a permanent information record. If the answers from the other question are not sufficient, then asking a new question about them won't make anything better.

Answer (score 0):

Those spatulas came in many colors, mine were white, I've seen them in pink, green and black. I don't believe they are being made anymore (and I have looked. It's my favorite spatula by far). They were made by Foley. [This answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/43126/35357) was the last answer to the original question, and eBay is the only place I have seen them other than secondhand thrift shops.